# Windows (+VirtualBox) не видят intel VT-x

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v

- Windows 10 Pro Ver 1703 (15063.413)
- Intel Core i7 6700K
- Виртуализация
  в биосе включена

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Hyper-V установлен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При инсталяции новой виртуальной машины в виртуалбоксе не вижу x64 вариантов.
Intel(R) Processor Identification Utility говорит, что
Intel Virtualization Technology = No, хотя в линуксовом хосту всё работает

Возможно кто-то встречался с похожими симтомами, и знает варианты лечения.
Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Hyper-V установлен

В этом и есть ваша проблема.
Удалите его – VT-x заработает.

Он конкурирует с VirtualBox, равно как и с VMware, за доступ к аппаратному ускорению виртуализации.

Когда решал эту же проблему самостоятельно, способов отвязать VT-x от Hyper-V с помощью настроек не нашел, но удаление помогло.

Comment: Да. Это действительно помогло.
При этом я в процессе поиска решения удалял Hyper-V, но, возможно, не доребутался. Ставил же его по старой привычке от процессора AMD.